# AWS SAM HttpApiGateway Lambda Authorizer: grant permission to invoke Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm not able to programmatically enable the "grant API Gateway permission to invoke your Lambda function" that is available in [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54N5.png) from my SAM template:

```
  MyApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          TokenAuthorizer:
            AuthorizerPayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt TokenAuthorizer.Arn
            Identity:
              Headers:  
                - Authorization
      StageName: v1

  TokenAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: auth/
      Handler: auth
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-authorizer
      Runtime: go1.x
```

Comment: In standard CF you would use a "AWS::Lambda::Permission" resource to grant access. I assume there's a similar serverless version (or perhaps that resource works fine in serverless).

Comment: 404 (nice handle!!!) I don't think this is serverless.